# Prove that $f'(0)$ does not exist for the given function $f(x)$

Tags: calculus

If we want to show this we must show that $f$ is not *differentiable* at $x=0$.

The function is defined as follows:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}, & \text{if $x\ne0$} \\
0,  &\text{if $x=0$} 
\end{cases}
$$  which is a piecewise function.

I say $f'(0)$ is not defined because $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1$ but $f(0) = 0$ is not the same value, so $f'(0)$ DNE, so $f$ is not *differentiable* at $0$, but my professor say this is completely bad!

I say $\lim_{x \to 0} x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$.  But I think this is not right and I don't know how to show this does not exist!

Comment: (sin u)/u approaches 1 as u approaches 0. But 1/x is not at all like u. It's not approaching 0.

Comment: In fact, the limit of f(x) as x approaches 0 _does_ exist (and is equal to 0) --.use the squeeze theoeem. For any nonzero value of x, the value of f(x) is between -|x| and |x| inclusive.

Comment: But the fact that f(x) approaches a limit as x approaches 0 doesn't imply that f'(0) exists. It only implies that f is continuous at x = 0.(since f(0) = 0 and the limit is also 0).

Comment: If you think about the graph of f(x) near x = 0, it will become clear why f'(0) does not exist. As x approaches 0. you can select a sequence of points in the domain such that the slope of the secants is 1. But for some other sequence, you can get secants with slope -1. That already shows that the limit, as h approaches 0, of (f(0+h) - f(0))/h does not exist.

Comment: Seems that you are confusing $x\to0$ and $1/x\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h\sin\dfrac1h-0}h=\lim_{h\to0}\sin\dfrac1h=\lim_{t\to\infty}\sin t$$

doesn't exist (because for any $L$, $\max(|\sin t-L|)\ge 1$).

Answer (score 0):

First, $\lim_{x\to 0}x\sin(1/x)=0\ne 1$.  To show this, simply note that that given $\epsilon>0$

$$|x\sin(1/x)|\le |x|<\epsilon$$

whenever $|x|<\delta=\epsilon$.  And we are done with that.

> In the OP, from L'Hospital's Rule, the limit,
>
> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}=0$$
>
> since the numerator is bounded by $1$ in absolute value and the denominator approaches infinity.

---

Next, if $f'(0)$ exists, then $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\sin(1/h)$ exists.

But, let $\epsilon=1$.  Then, for all $\delta>0$ we can take $x=\frac{1}{2n\pi +t}$, $t\in (0,2\pi)$,and by choosing $n$ sufficiently large, we force $|x|<\delta$.

Then, for this $|x|<\delta$, we see that

$|\sin(1/x)|=|\sin(t)|$

By choosing $t\in (0,2\pi)$, we can make $|\sin(1/x)-L|=|\sin(t)-L|\ge 1=\epsilon$ for any $L\in [-1,1]$.

> Thus the limit fails to exist and $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to given you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

we have $-1< sin(1/x)<1$ implies that $-x< x*sin(1/x) <x$

finally $lim x→0 (x*sin(1/x))$ = $limx→0$  $x$ = $lim$ x→0 $-x$ = $0$

sandwich theorem

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! Your answer is not bad, but it could be better written. For example, this site uses MathJax for formulae ; here are some tips http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer Moreover, it is recommended to write grammatically correct answers (see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), to make it easier to read and more useful to the community.

Comment: Also your answer doesn't answer why the derivative at x=0 doesn't exist.